# What is the radix parameter in Java, and how does it work?

Tags: java, wrapper, numeric, radix

I understand that radix for the function `Integer.parseInt()` is the base to convert the string into. Shouldn't 11 base 10 converted with a radix/base 16 be a `B` instead of `17`?

The following code prints 17 according to the textbook:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( Integer.parseInt("11", 16) );
  }
}
```

Comment: The other way round.  You're asking it to interpret `"11"` in base-16.  i.e. 1*16 + 1.

Comment: @MinhTran Please checkmark the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you perform the `ParseInt` operation with the radix, the 11 base 16 is parsed as 17, which is a simple value. It is then printed as radix 10.

You want:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(11, 16));
```

This takes the decimal value 11(not having a base at the moment, like having "eleven" watermelons(one more than the number of fingers a person has)) and prints it with radix 16, resulting in `B`.

When we take an `int` value it's stored as base 2 within the computer's physical memory (in nearly all cases) but this is irrelevant since the parse and tostring conversions work with an arbitrary radix (10 by default).

Answer (score 6):

It's actually taking `11` in hex and converting it to decimal. So for example if you had the same code but with `"A"` in the string, it would output `10`.

Answer (score 6):

Here,

```
public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("11", 16));
    }
}
```

**11** is **16** based number and should be converted at 10 i.e decimal.

```
 So, integer of (11)16 = 1*16^1 +1*16^0 = 16+1 = 17
```

Answer (score 5):

you basically telling to parse 11 as if it was base 16
so if you know how to convert from hex to decimal
it will look like this
11 in hex = ((16^0 ) * 1) + ((16^1) * 1) = 17 in decimal

if you want to convert from base 10 to any base use:

```
Integer.toString(11, 16); //HEXA
output: b
Integer.toString(11, 10); //decimal
output: 11
Integer.toString(11, 8);  //octal
output: 13
Integer.toString(11, 2);  //Binary
output: 1011
```

Comment: This must be answer, voted up.

Answer (score 1):

The function act backwards as you think. You convert "11" in base 16 to base 10, so the result is 17.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from base 10 to base 16 use

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(11, 16));
```

Output will be b.